# App crashing on load terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have been playing around with a project of mine tonight and now I can't get it to load up. Strange thing is I have got an older version of this and have even tried to copy all data across and still not loading.

Error I am getting in `NSLog` is as follows:

```
2014-04-01 01:24:53.513 Adult Game[47180:a0b] CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: , or invalid scale factor: 2.000000
2014-04-01 01:24:53.515 Adult Game[47180:a0b] Could not load the "" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "DannyLinton.Adult-Game"
2014-04-01 01:24:53.519 Adult Game[47180:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ViewController 0x8e35860> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key animate.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0196f5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x016f28b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x019ff6a1 -[NSException raise] + 17
    3   Foundation                          0x013b39ee -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 282
    4   Foundation                          0x0131fcfb _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 88
    5   Foundation                          0x0131f253 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 267
    6   Foundation                          0x0138170a -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 412
    7   UIKit                               0x00702a15 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 106
    8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x017047d2 -[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x0196ab6a -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 314
    10  UIKit                               0x0070156e -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1417
    11  UIKit                               0x00573605 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 280
    12  UIKit                               0x00573dad -[UIViewController loadView] + 302
    13  UIKit                               0x005740ae -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 78
    14  UIKit                               0x005745b4 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    15  UIKit                               0x0049c9fd -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 66
    16  UIKit                               0x0049cd97 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 312
    17  UIKit                               0x0049d02d -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
    18  UIKit                               0x004a789a -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 65
    19  UIKit                               0x0045acd0 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1851
    20  UIKit                               0x0045f3a8 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
    21  UIKit                               0x0047387c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3447
    22  UIKit                               0x00473de9 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
    23  UIKit                               0x00461025 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 736
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x031042f6 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x03103e01 PurpleEventCallback + 46
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x018ead65 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x018eaa9b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x0191577c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x01914ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x019148db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    31  UIKit                               0x0045eadd -[UIApplication _run] + 840
    32  UIKit                               0x00460d3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    33  Adult Game                          0x00007dad main + 141
    34  libdyld.dylib                       0x02df2725 start + 0
    35  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a phantom connection in your StoryBoard or XIB file called "animate".

1. Open your StoryBoard / XIB file
2. If you are using a StoryBoard, select the AdultGame view controller
3. Click on the "File's Owner" along the left
4. Select "View > Utilities > Show Connections Inspector"
5. You will see a list of "Outlets". One of them will be called "animate" and have an exclamation point next to it. Click on the little "x" to delete it.

Comment: Ok im new to xcode how do i open the xib im working on storyboard ?

Comment: Ok ok, there won't be a xib then. Just in the storyboard select the AdultGame view controller and start at step number 2.

Comment: ohh i think i found it

Comment: 2014-04-01 01:59:44.827 Adult Game[47567:a0b] -[ViewController option:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x89cc2e0
2014-04-01 01:59:44.833 Adult Game[47567:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController option:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x89cc2e0'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: I now have that error when i click to change to a new view controller within the app? hmm

Comment: @GhasemTabatabaei Ummm with all do respect, I wrote mine myself. If anyone copied anybody, that video copied this response. Mine was written in Apr 2014 and that video was posted in July 2014. Not only that, the description of that video links to this answer. Please be sure you are right before you insult someone.

Comment: This worked! Thanks for your help, its really driving me crazy